# ECDSA Signature Verification Failed on Javascript(Elliptic)

Tags: javascript, signature, javacard, ecdsa

I have an issue with verification of a ECDSA Signature made on javacard. I am trying to verify the signature in Javascript(Elliptic) but the verification always fails.

My applet(*javacard*) looks like:

```
//initialization
ecdsa = Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_ECDSA_SHA_256, false);
eccKey=SecP256k1.newKeyPair(); //in SecP256k1 the p,a,b,g,r,k are set
eccKey.genKeyPair();

//singing method
ecdsa.init(eccKey.getPrivate(), Signature.MODE_SIGN);

//Generates the signature of all input data.
short lenTmp = ecdsa.sign(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, (short)1, buffer, 
(short)0);
//I tried also to sigh precomputed hash - same result
/*short lenTmp = ecdsa.signPreComputedHash(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, 
len, buffer, (short)0); */

apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, lenTmp);
```

I get a private key 
`(e.g. : 3E05E289911E66A8153EE9C15A0AFC109C49207DB9DC4656CC4D092323EA65BC)`

When I sign a message `(e.g : 0x01)`

I get the signature in DER format:
`304402205F376BB2B2D48BBB0275099C3B9591F18ECA424DD953EB27FDE37BA819B98F980220539A85B91491E977F6B31B5A76BEF6805BBC3B6481A51C23B9E7C6F39FB70569`

Also its verification is successful on javacard..
But when I try to verify it on nodejs, it always fails.
My code looks like:

```
let elliptic = require('elliptic');
let ec = new elliptic.ec('secp256k1');
let keyPair = ec.keyFromPrivate("3E05E289911E66A8153EE9C15A0AFC109C49207DB9DC4656CC4D092323EA65BC");
let privKey = keyPair.getPrivate("hex");
let pubKey = keyPair.getPublic();
let signature = "304402205F376BB2B2D48BBB0275099C3B9591F18ECA424DD953EB27FDE37BA819B98F980220539A85B91491E977F6B31B5A76BEF6805BBC3B6481A51C23B9E7C6F39FB70569";
let msg = 0x01;
let validSig = ec.verify(msg, signature, pubKey);
console.log("Signature valid?", validSig);//returns always false
```

Also, if I sign the same message with the same key on nodejs, the verification is successful.

Moreover, I noticed that the signature is always different in javacard, while the signature on elliptic is always the same, maybe it always chosses the same random k.

Comment: I presume that the error is in `SecP256k1.newKeyPair()`, please include it...

Comment: Voted to close this question as the required info is missing, which imho makes it impossible to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely caused due to the fact that standard ecdsa libraries in java/go/python/etc. generate the signature der encoded where as the javascript library simply concatenates the R and S values of the signature. Here is how I deal with this issue in my own library [HERE](https://github.com/syncaide/flats/blob/master/src/message_test.go#L132). Sorry the example is golang to typescript, but hopefully you can reverse engineer this to java/javascript. Event within Node.js this issue exists. Here is a [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554165/ecdsa-signatures-between-node-js-and-webcrypto-appear-to-be-incompatible) to a discussion that ultimately helped me figure out how to breach the gap between the implementations within my own work.

Comment: I made a signature also on javascript(using same private key and message) and the result is also in DER format(not only r and s concatenated), but I get the same signature always:
    `304402206d55364f9eff56dcff626467920ea8c2fed44653009cde369546cc98da3b2be00220086abcc4a127c5ac1dcb5d7c4da51fca96a75e70cdeeb6bc746010345a691beb`

Comment: Hmmm... I remember having the same issue when I tried using the `elliptic` library. Ultimately I did solve that issue. Instead I decided to simply rely on the browser builtin `crypto.subtle` library. Sorry can't help with this one. Generally speaking though, the signature should always be different because of a random factor inside of it. So if it is always the same value, there is definitely an issue. If you end up swapping to `subtle.crypto` feel free to bug me for more questions. I did loads of work with the spec for it and understand it pretty well.

Comment: I'm facing his issue, my signature from golang code cannot verified from node server. Can you share you code again? 
Thank you