# WebCrypto Generate ECDSA signature in base64

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-crypto, subtlecrypto

I wanna generate an ECDSA signature and convert it to base64.

I can easily accomplish this with Nodejs:

```
  const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256')
  sign.update('part1')
  sign.update('part2')
  const signature = sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64')
```

However, when I try to do the same with Javascript SubtleCrypto API, The generated signature is not valid when validated with Node Crypto.
Here is my code:

```
 let signature = await window.crypto.subtle.sign(
  {
    name: "ECDSA",
    hash: { name: "SHA-256" },
  },
  this.privateKey,
  "part1"+"part2"
);

signature = new Uint8Array(signature);

const byteArray = new Uint8Array(signature);
let byteString = "";
for (let i = 0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i += 1) {
  byteString += String.fromCharCode(byteArray[i]);
}
const b64Signature = window.btoa(byteString);
```

What Am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in signature encoding format. See [ECDSA signatures between Node.js and WebCrypto appear to be incompatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554165/ecdsa-signatures-between-node-js-and-webcrypto-appear-to-be-incompatible)

Here are some examples of how you can convert WebCrypto signature to NodeJS and back

https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/webcrypto/blob/master/src/mechs/ec/crypto.ts#L62-L69
https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/webcrypto/blob/master/src/mechs/ec/crypto.ts#L84-L89